# Audio playback code broke with new version of Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, audio

first I have to say, I'm a beginner with iOS development. I would appreciate any help.
I've made a code that plays sounds when certain buttons are touched, it worked fine in previous Xcode version, but in this new one, no sounds are played. During the building of code no errors are reported and everything else works fine when I turn on simulator for iPhone 4s, that one is target for this code. Please help.

Here is my code:
file.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface DataViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate> {
    int nob, nof, nod;
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *maxDistanceLabel;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray *fetchedSettingsArray;

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSNumber *numB;
- (IBAction)forwardB:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)backB:(id)sender;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *numberB;
@end
```

file.m (just part where the audio needs to play)

```
- (IBAction)forwardB:(id)sender {
    nob ++;
    NSString *nobStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",nob];
    [numberB setText:nobStr];
     numB=[NSNumber numberWithInt:nob];
    //sound at button touch
    NSString *effectTitle;
    effectTitle =@"Buckklick";
    SystemSoundID soundID;
    NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:effectTitle ofType:@"wav"];
    NSURL *soundUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID ((__bridge CFURLRef)soundUrl, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found explanation in some other discussion. Apparently simulator is not working properly. 
And I found solution, simply downloading Xcode 5.1.1 to finish my project.